# Constructor Injection in Restler

Tags: php, rest, restler

Is it possible to do pass along arguments to an API class for the sake of constructor injection? For example, in index.php I have the following:

```
$r->addAPIClass('Contacts', '');
```

And Contacts.php looks something like this:

```
class Contacts
{
    private $v;

    public function __construct(Validation v)
    {
        $this->v = v;
    }
}
```

How would I do this with Restler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restler 3 RC5 has a dependency injection container called `Scope` which is responsible for creating new instances of any class from their name, it comes in handy for this purpose.

Once you register the Contacts class with its dependency using the register method, it will be lazy instantiated when asked for

```
<?php
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Luracast\Restler\Scope;
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

Scope::register('Contacts', function () {
    return new Contacts(Scope::get('Validation'));
});

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Contacts', '');
$r->handle();
```

By using `Scope::get('Validation')` we can register `Validation` too if it has any dependencies

Comment: That's awesome! Is there documentation anywhere on RC5? I'm currently on RC4 and don't see anything about RC5 on the Restler page.

Comment: RC5 is just waiting for documentation to be completed to be moved to the master branch, It will happen soon!